# Crystal Reports v12 Crosstab with Data Grouped / Totaled in More Than Two Directions

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports, crosstab

I need to replicate a report that was written in Webi while only having access to Crystal Reports.  The basic format appears to require a cross tab with the following characteristics:
1. Names of Officers will be the columns with a total to the right (easy part)
2. Rows are not subsets of each other like a normal cross tab:

- 1st row is starting loan $ balances
- 2nd row is $ transfers into loan balances for the period (calculation)
- 3rd row is # of relationships for the $ transfers in (calculation)

3. In short I have to document in separate rows $ and # into and out loan balances with officers across the page.

I'd appreciate insight on how to accomplish this as most of the cross tabs I've created are fairly standard. I'm using SQL 2005 to pull in all the base data.

Comment: @Criag How far did wrote the report? Please show your work?

Comment: Hiten004 Tks for the response! I'm still only toying with a very basic crosstab format - unfortunately, it's not yet even remotely useful to aid in answering my question. I can provide an Excel format of what I need to produce if that helps.

Comment: without see data structure (table) and some basic report definition. it hard to help.

Comment: Hiten004 - sorry, I understand.  I am currently experimenting with a 'cross tab multi-line with formulas style Crystal Report and that might be my solution.  I may also need to rewrite the SQL to get the data in a format to facilitate the solution, but I will follow-up and THANK YOU.